Problem with debugging in geany: the system cannot find the specified file
I'm on Windows 10 and have Geany on version 2.0 with the plugin "Scoped Debugger: Relatively simple interface to GDB." installed.
To debug a program, what I am trying to do is compile it in the following way:
g++ -Wall -g -DTEST --debug -o "pruebas_varias" "pruebas_varias.cpp"

(in the directory: C:\Users\Username\Documents)
And then in the menus I go to Debug->Configure program and where it says "Executable: " I put "C:\Users\Username\Documents\pruebas_varias.exe" (without the quotes).
But when I go to run it I get the error:
"Error creating process /c/Program Files/Geany/C:\Users\Username\Documents\various_tests.exe, (error 2: The system cannot find the specified file.)"

Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong? On Ubuntu Mate 22.04 I tried it the same way and it seems to work fine.
